# Labels That Look Exactly Like Expander

Tags: wpf, styles, label, expander

In WPF I'd like to have an expander that shows a stack of labels that have the exact style as the default expander; rounded corners, black border, except the open/close image.

Anyone got a style for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to extract a style from the default Expander style but i think it might be a bit different, also note that by default there is no visible border, so you will not see the rounded edges unless you change the respective brush or use a background colour:

```
    <Style x:Key="LabelExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0">
                         <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here is the complete default style if you want to try yourself, all the header styles and triggers are irrelevant since they are used for the ToggleButton which you do not want in a Label:

```
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                                            <TransformCollection>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                            </TransformCollection>
                                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="DarkGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#FF003366"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DefaultExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```